# Merge Intervals in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

This is a task taken from [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/) -

> *Given a collection of intervals, merge all overlapping intervals.*
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: [[1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
>
> Output: [[1,6],[8,10],[15,18]]
>
> /** Explanation: Since intervals `[1,3]` and `[2,6]` overlap, merge them into `[1,6]`. */
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: [[1,4],[4,5]]
>
> Output: [[1,5]]
>
> /** Explanation: Intervals `[1,4]` and `[4,5]` are considered overlapping. */
> ```

**My imperative solution** -

```
 /**
   * @param {number[][]} intervals
   * @return {number[][]}
   */
  var merge = function(intervals) {  
    const sortedIntervals = intervals.sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0]);
    const newIntervals = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
      if (!newIntervals.length || newIntervals[newIntervals.length - 1][1] < sortedIntervals[i][0]) {
        newIntervals.push(sortedIntervals[i]);
      } else {
        newIntervals[newIntervals.length - 1][1] = Math.max(newIntervals[newIntervals.length - 1][1], sortedIntervals[i][1]);
      }
    }
    return newIntervals;
  };
```

**My functional solution** -

```
/**
 * @param {number[][]} intervals
 * @return {number[][]}
 */
function merge(intervals) {
  const mergeInterval = (ac, x) => (!ac.length || ac[ac.length - 1][1] < x[0]
    ? ac.push(x)
    : ac[ac.length - 1][1] = Math.max(ac[ac.length - 1][1], x[1]), ac);

  return intervals
    .sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0])
    .reduce(mergeInterval, []);
};
```

Comment: While sorting intervals on first value suggests itself, I'm wondering if discarding/merging intervals during sort make a notable difference, and in what direction. (Obviously, it doesn't change a thing if no intervals get merged.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is mostly readable and clear:

- the variable names are descriptive (for the most part - `x` is a little unclear)
- there is good use of `const` and `let` instead of `var`

Some of the lines are a little lengthy - the longest line appears to be 117 characters long (excluding indentation):

> ```
> newIntervals[newIntervals.length - 1][1] = Math.max(newIntervals[newIntervals.length - 1][1], sortedIntervals[i][1]);
> ```

I considered suggesting that a `for...of` loop be used to replace the `for` loop in the imperative solution after seeing the suggestion to use `arr.entries()` in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/229870/120114) which would allow the use of a variable like `interval` instead of `sortedIntervals[i]`, though when comparing in FF and chrome with [this jsPerf test](https://jsperf.com/sorting-intervals) it seems that would be slower and thus less optimal, perhaps because each iteration would have an added function call.

When `intervals.sort()` is called the array is sorted in-place so `intervals` could be used instead of `sortedIntervals`, however it does seem that using `sortedIntervals`. That would reduce the storage by \$O(n)\$.