# Selection Sort Algorithm (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, recursion, node.js

I wanted to implement a selection sort and wanted to make sure that I'm doing it correctly. I wanted to do it in a way that's efficient and use recursion. Please let me know if I am doing this correctly or if there is a better way for me to do it.

```
 /**
 * selectionSort
 * @param toSort
 * @param sorted
 * @returns {Array}
 */
function selectionSort(toSort, sorted=[]) {
    if (!toSort.length) {
        return sorted;
    }
    let minIndex = findMinimum(toSort);
    sorted.push(...toSort.splice(minIndex, 1))
    return selectionSort(toSort, sorted);
}

function findMinimum(arr) {
    let minIndex=0;
    arr.forEach(function (item, index) {
        if(item < arr[minIndex]) {
            minIndex = index;
        }
    })
    return minIndex;
}


const testCase = [64, 25, 12, 22, 11]
const answer = selectionSort(testCase);
```

Comment: Is this code using node.js?

Comment: Why use recursion when a loop would do just fine?  Recursion is just going to have a lot of stack buildup for large arrays and extra function calls.

Comment: A `for` loop is generally more efficient than `.forEach()` as there's no function call and new scope involved.   Probably best to use `for/of`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm trying to familiarize myself with recursion more. I didn't know that it's better to use loops in some cases. Thanks for the tip with the `for/of` also

Answer (score 5):

#### Review

- `findMinimum` means to me that you find the minimum *value* in an array of items. Since your function returns the *index* instead, call it `indexOfMinimum`.
- Prefer the use of `const` over `let` if you only assign a variable once: `let minIndex = findMinimum(toSort);` -> `const minIndex = findMinimum(toSort);`.
- Use arrow notation to write more compact functions: `function (item, index)` -> `(item, index) =>`.
- Your documentation seems like wasted space. If you document a public function (which is a good thing), put in some effort to write a clear description of the function, not just the name of the method copied.
- Use whitespace to write more idiomatic javascript:

  - `let minIndex=0;` ->  `let minIndex = 0;`
  - `if(item < arr[minIndex])` -> `if (item < arr[minIndex])`

Rewritten:

```
function selectionSort(toSort, sorted=[]) {
    if (!toSort.length) {
        return sorted;
    }
    const minIndex = indexOfMinimum(toSort);
    sorted.push(...toSort.splice(minIndex, 1))
    return selectionSort(toSort, sorted);
}

function indexOfMinimum(arr) {
    let minIndex = 0;
    arr.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (item < arr[minIndex]) {
            minIndex = index;
        }
    })
    return minIndex;
}
```

Comment: Those are good suggestions. Thank you.

What do you mean by more idiomatic javascript?

Comment: I mean by following more standard practices, or in this case conventions and style guides.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest the following changes:

1. Use a loop instead of recursion
2. Use `for/of` instead of `.forEach()`
3. push a single value instead of using an array with one element in it
4. cache the lowest value so far so you don't have to constantly refetch it on every comparison
5. Use a temporary array for the sort so the function is non-destructive to the source array (consistent with most array methods)
6. Use `const` where you can.

Code:

```
 /**
     * selectionSort
     * @param toSort (not modified)
     * @param sorted (new sorted array)
     * @returns {Array}
     */
    function selectionSort(toSort, sorted = []) {
        if (!toSort.length) {
            return sorted;
        }
        // make copy so we don't modify source
        const sortData =  toSort.slice();

        while (sortData.length) {
            const minIndex = findMinimum(sortData);
            sorted.push(sortData[minIndex]);
            // remove min item from data left to be sorted
            sortData.splice(minIndex, 1);
        }
        return sorted;
    }

    function findMinimum(arr) {
        let minIndex = 0, minValue = arr[0];
        for (const [index, item] of arr.entries()) {
            if (item < minValue) {
                minIndex = index;
                minValue = item;
            }
        }
        return minIndex;
    }


    const testCase = [64, 25, 12, 22, 11]
    const answer = selectionSort(testCase);
    console.log(answer);
```

Comment: I disagree with `for...of...entries` though. There is nothing wrong with using normal `for` when the use case is exactly what it was designed for. JS communitie's overuse of new constructs where they bring no benefit over the old ones is harmful for code readability and consistency.

Comment: @TomášZato - I have no problem with a regular `for` loop.   The OP was using `.forEach()` which I did not think was as good as some type of a `for` loop.  In this case, the OP actually needs both the index and the value which `for/of` and `.entries()` hands you on a silver platter, thus why I used it.

Comment: I apologize, I read the post again and noticed that I misread `arr.entries` for `Object.entries(arr)`. `arr.entries` is great.